# Embed HTML content from another http request without an iframe

Tags: html

I want certain content on the website (data tables) to be available for including in other pages (like articles) on the same web site. I imagine the "Paste this code into article where you want the table: [..]" route.

I don't want an iframe, I want the html directly inserted (I already have the GET API that returns html table as one of the possible formats).

Is there a way how this is intended to be done in HTML?

I have looked around another questions but those seem to mainly struggle with CORS which is not an issue in my case.

My naive attepmt would be to make embed code like this:

```
<div 
    class="replace-me-by-src-content" 
    data-src="http://the.long.url" >
</div>
```

And the loading would be done by some ever-present javascript that would take care of each `.replace-me-by-src-content` element.

Is there a cleaner way without using javascript? You know - we can directly insert images or stylesheets by just providing the src attribute in certain tags and the browser takes care of doing the GET request and inserting the response. Can the same be done for plain html inserts?

Comment: With only HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use object to load the external page.

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com" style="width:100%; height:100%"></object>
```

Or else you need to use jquery.

```
<script>$("#testLoad").load("http://www.example.com");</script>
<div id="testLoad"></div>
```

```html
<object type="text/html" data="https://www.example.com" style="width:100%; height:100%"></object>
```

Comment: Nice, it seems that `object` tag is exactly what I was looking for. Will check how it works in my case.